The number of possible player pairings in a tournament with $2n-1$ rounds
In a game where two players compete against each other, suppose there is a tournament with $2n$ players. Over the course of $2n-1$ rounds, any two players face each other once. How many arrangments of the $2n-1$ rounds are possible?
For example, given 6 players numbered from 1 to 6 and using the notation $(i,j)$ to indicate that players $i$ and $j$ face each other in the current round, here are two possible arrangements of the 5 rounds:
Round 1:
(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
Round 2:
(1,3) (4,6) (2,5)
Round 3:
(1,4) (3,5) (2,6)
Round 4:
(1,5) (3,6) (2,4)
Round 5:
(1,6) (2,3) (4,5)
Another arrangement:
Round 1:
(1,2) (3,5) (4,6)
Round 2:
(1,3) (2,4) (5,6)
Round 3:
(1,4) (2,5) (3,6)
Round 4:
(1,5) (2,6) (3,4)
Round 5:
(1,6) (2,3) (4,5)
In every arrangement, the numbering of the rounds is irrelevant, i.e., it doesn't matter which pairing occurs in which round. If the pairings are not identical, then the arrangements are different. For example if, in a certain arrangement, in the round where player 1 faces player 4, player 2 faces player 5, then a different arrangement has, for instance, player 2 facing player 6 while player 1 is facing player 4.
I tried to use basic counting arguments. I also tried to characterise the properties of the permutations through applying which, an arrangement can be generated given a single round, but the patterns are complicated and require frequent case by case exclusion at certain steps.

This problem is equivalent to taking a complete graph, where each player is a node and each edge is a match between two players, and partitioning it into sets of edges (rounds) such that each node appears once in each round.
This process is known as a 1-factorization, and the number of 1-factorizations of the complete graph is given by OEIS/A000438. As far as I am aware, there is no closed expression for this answer. It grows extremely quickly, and indeed the OEIS table only goes up to $n=7$ at approx. $9.9\cdot 10^{28}$.
